# Treasures are delicious

Tags: riddle, word

> 12 treasures in a chest. Crack me open and liquid gold comes out. What am I?

It's easy if you look at the question carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Eggs. There's often twelve in a carton and they're full of yellow yolk.

Comment: That was very eggxcellent